grub-install /dev/sda failed on Linux Mint. efibootmgr cannot detect boot variables
I have been trying to install Linux Mint 22 "Wilma" alongside Windows 10 on my computer. I've reserved 80 GB of free unpartitioned space on my SSD and burned the image on an USB with Rufus (I also tryied with Ventoy) to install from the LiveCD GUI. And it goes well until almost the end of the installation, when it throws the error grub-install /dev/sda failed. This is a fatal error. I've tryied and checked everything the answers online said, and yet it's always the same error. I confirmed the checksums of the ISO I downloaded (from Mint website) and executed Boot Repair, but it seem to be fine with the image. I assured I am booting in UEFI mode (ventoy confirms it on its startup screen), disabled secure boot and legacy mode in bios options, disabled fast startup on energy settings, and made aware that the USB is configured for GPT partition scheme, either in Rufus and Ventoy, which coincides with my disk's partition scheme. I even tryied managing the partitions myself according to the instructions I got from people I asked, for example creating an EFI partition in addition to the Windows EFI and telling the installer to put the boot there, but none of all that worked. However, I discovered what I think it's a clue, and is that, when I execute command sudo efibootmgr the output says:
Skipping unreadable variable "Boot0000": Input/output error
Skipping unreadable variable "Boot0001": Input/output error
Skipping unreadable variable "Boot0002": Input/output error
Skipping unreadable variable "Boot2001": Input/output error
Skipping unreadable variable "Boot3002": Input/output error

I think solving that would put me very close to finally being able to install Mint on my computer. I also tryied with Manjaro and it's installation throws exactly the same error. Have to say I'm a newbie using Linux and want to install it because of it's performance and liberty to configure your PC as you wish, but I still want to keep Windows to feel safe during the transition. And I am installing in a laptop, so there's no chance to install to a second disk to avoid the problem or something. I want to solve it, and I would really appreciate if you can help me with this

Perhaps your system has an UEFI firmware bug which complicates accessing UEFI boot variables through the UEFI Runtime Services, and Windows has a workaround for it but Mint hasn't? If so, only a firmware update ("BIOS update") might help.

Indeed, as above. If the problem persists after having the latest UEFI version then this workaround is probably in order: https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/comment/605199/#Comment_605199

What brand/model system? HP's require you to use System settings to change UEFI boot order. Acer's require you to set "trust" on UEFI boot entries. Have not seen that particular error on efibootmgr listing.

See my self answered question: UEFI Resolution Woes.  I have since dropped FreeBSD, but the issue still exists.  I cannot set any EFI variable from any Linux. I must use the BBS setting on my motherboard or boot into a UEFI Shell from USB if I lose my rEFInd boot entry.

My laptop is an HP Pavillion x360 Convertible, I changed the boot order to first boot from USB as one of the first things I did. My bios, I think is of model Insyide F.52, I dont remember well, but I dont think thats the problem. The curious thing is, that after the installation finishes with that error, in the boot options there is an entry to boot from some "Ubuntu" and when I select it it starts Mint :) I guess its full installed, but the part that couldnt be installed isnt essential

This is a shot in the air, maybe adding a password for admin in the UEFI settings?
